# Como Obtener todos los valores de una Consulta SQL dentro de For en PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, array, bucle-for

tengo el siguiente código donde hago una consulta dentro de un for y cuando quiero retornar ese valor solo obtengo el ultimo registro , es el ultimo valor que tuvo el ciclo ($i  mi contador en el  for). quiersa saber como mantener los diferentes resultado del For.

```
 if($result){

            $reporte=array();
            for($i=0;$i<$cuantos;$i++){

                 $reportadas[]=[];
                 $iduser1=$result[$i]->IDUSER;


                $reporte=array(DB::select("SELECT IDUSER,SUM(hor) as  total,(ROUND(((sum(hor)*100)/45),2,0)) as EficienciaReal
                  from
                  (SELECT IDUSER,TIEMPO,(TIEMPO/60) as hor 
                   FROM [dbo].[datos]
                   where  fecha between '{$fech1}' and '{$fech2}' and IDUSER=$iduser1) as T1
                  Group by IDUSER"));
             }

           var_dump($reporte); 
           /*
                   return view("estancia.datos")
                        ->with("result",$result)
                        ->with("reporte",$reporte);*/
```

solo si pongo el var_dum($reporte) dentro del for puedo ver el array con mis resultados completos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
de lo contratio obtengo esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como bien dice @alanfcm, estás sobreescribiendo la variable, no llenando un array de resultados. Aunque no entiendo el sentido de enviar tantas consultas a la base de datos dentro de un bucle. Nunca me pareció una buena idea consultar a la base de datos dentro de bucles. ¿Esos datos no se pueden obtener en una sola consulta, por qué un bucle?

Comment: Lo hago así porque llenare un reporte con esta información y constantemente los criterios que le envió están cambiando, la otra manera seria hacer un procedimiento almacenado en SQL pero de cualquier manera tendría que ocupar un bucle para estar mandarlo a llamar cada que se hiciera el reporte que repito siempre tiene parámetros distintos. @A.Cedano. agradezco tu comentario de ante mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas sobreescribiendo la variable en cada iteracion.  Necesitas crear un array con los resultados asi:

```
if($result){

        $reporte=array();
        for($i=0;$i<$cuantos;$i++){

             $reportadas[]=[];
             $iduser1=$result[$i]->IDUSER;


            $reporte[]=array(DB::select("SELECT IDUSER,SUM(hor) as  total,(ROUND(((sum(hor)*100)/45),2,0)) as EficienciaReal
              from
              (SELECT IDUSER,TIEMPO,(TIEMPO/60) as hor 
               FROM [dbo].[datos]
               where  fecha between '{$fech1}' and '{$fech2}' and IDUSER=$iduser1) as T1
              Group by IDUSER"));
         }

       var_dump($reporte); 
       /*
               return view("estancia.datos")
                    ->with("result",$result)
                    ->with("reporte",$reporte);*/
```

Comment: te lo agradezco funciono sin problema.